# Log specification in regression model

Tags: regression, logarithm

I'm working with a basic linear regression model, and I have a question about the specification of the predictor. Consider this basic regression model:

\begin{equation}
g_{i,t} = \alpha + \beta_1 \ln(h_{i,t}) + \beta_2 \Delta \ln(h_{i,t}) + u_{i,t}
\end{equation}

where $h_{i,t}$ is the stock of knowledge for the $i$-th firm at time $t$, and $g_{i,t}$ is the growth rate of profits.

If I specify $h_{i,t}$ in logarithms, does it imply that the stock of $h$ increases by more for an additional increase in $h$ for lower values of $h$ because the logarithmic function has diminishing (but still positive) marginal returns? In other words, the slope of $\ln(h_{i,t})$ is larger for lower values of $h$. Is my intuition correct?

A remark, I'm not referring to the partial effect of $ln(h_{i,t})$ on $g_{i,t}$. I'm referring to the log-specification of $h$
which in economics is a predetermined variable since it’s a stock variable. My point is on the motion of difference equation $\Delta
h$